# C++ implicit conversion: Why should literal string convert to string?

Tags: c++, string

The example is from Chapter 7 in `C++ Primer 5th`.

Suppose class `Sales_data` has such constructor:

```
Sales_data(const std::string &s): bookNo(s) { }
```

And it has a public function member:

```
Sales_data &combine(Sales_data &s){...}
```

The flowing is error:(`item` is a `Sales_data` instance)

```
item.combine("9-999-9999");
```

The reason is that: **Only One Class-Type Conversion Is Allowed**, however, the code mentioned above has two user-defined conversions.

- "9-999-9999" to `string`
- `string` to `Sales_data`

Why should literal string convert to string ? Is `9-999-9999` not a `string` ?

Answer (score 3):

`"9-999-9999"` is not a string, it is a `const char[]`.  You can fix this by adding a constructor to you class that takes a `const char *` like:

```
Sales_data(const char* s): bookNo(s) { };
```

If you have C++14 support than you could also use a [std::string_literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
item.combine("9-999-9999"s);
```